# when i use <a href='sms:1234567890?body=123+456'>Send</a> to send a message in Android, the plus(+) will be changed space( )

Tags: javascript, html

when i use `<a href='sms:1234567890?body=123+456'>Send</a>` to send a message in Android:

```
    <a href='sms:1234567890?body=123+456'>Send</a>
```

the message content will be changed '123 456', the plus(+) is changed space( )

i try to use %2B to replace space( ):

```
    <a href='sms:1234567890?body=123%2B456'>Send</a>
```

but, its not work right

Comment: `%2B` should work. What are you getting instead of `+`?

Comment: its still got a space, whatever i use `%2B` or `%20`, its allways get a space. i cant understade why.

Comment: Try encoding the `%` as well: `%252B`

Comment: It sounds like a bug to me, it's decoding the hex, and then decoding it again.

Comment: Thanks for you, its work right now. i want to konw why its need run twice encodeURIComponent()

Comment: LIke I said, it sounds like a bug to me. It shouldn't decode it twice.

Comment: thank you for your answer sincerely again, i got it.